# Media queries work on chrome but not my mobile device

Tags: css, google-chrome, heroku, iphone-6-plus

I was adding media queries to fit different mobile devices, pushed my code to heroku and then it stopped working correctly. It didnt stop working until I added the other media quires so i deleted the rest and was left with what I started with and pushed it to heroku again and it still doesn't work. But If I look at it in chrome it works heres my code

```
    /* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

    /* Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen
      and (min-device-width: 414px)
      and (max-device-width: 736px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

    }

    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen
      and (min-device-width: 414px)
      and (max-device-width: 736px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
      and (orientation: portrait) {

        .site-name {
        font-family: Lato;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*font-size: 100px;*/
        font-size: 9.5vw;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 150px;
        }

        #split{
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen
      and (min-device-width: 414px)
      and (max-device-width: 736px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
      and (orientation: landscape) {

        #similar{
            width:50%;
        }
        /*  homescreen  posts*/
        #split{
            width:33%
        }
        /*  homescreen  title */
        .site-name {
        font-family: Lato;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*font-size: 100px;*/
        font-size: 9.5vw;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 150px;
        }


    }

    /* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 768px)
    and (max-device-width : 1024px)
    and (orientation : portrait)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  {

        #split{
            width:50%
        }

    }


    /* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 375px)
    and (max-device-width : 667px)
    and (orientation : landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  {

        #similar{
            width: 50%;
        }

        #split{
            width: 50%
        }

    }
```

EDIT I already have this in the head

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

so a missing meta tag is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'm new to queries and realized that when I removed the query for iphone six it worked i dont' think the order matters to chrome It' just looks for it and if it's there it works. Ive read media queries should start with the least and end with the greatest. Hopefully this helps someone else new to media queries.